# Determining Tab's Object at Run-time

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a tab control in WPF and want to get it's current (tab's) object at run-time. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple tab control:

```
<TabControl x:Name="tab">
    <TabItem Header="tab1">
        <TextBlock Text="text1"/>
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="tab2">
        <TextBlock Text="text2"/>
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

You can find the selected content using SelectedItem:

```
var x = tab.SelectedItem as TabItem;
MessageBox.Show(x.Header.ToString());//shows the header
var t = x.Content as TextBlock;
MessageBox.Show(t.Text);//shows the text of content
```

or simply by SelectedContent:

```
var x = tab.SelectedContent as TextBlock;
MessageBox.Show(x.Text);
```